# Android app with Kivy and Buildozer does not read WhatsApp chat correctly

Tags: python, android, kivy, bufferedreader, pyjnius

I am trying to make a simple android app with Kivy and buildozer, where I react to chats exported by WhatsApp. For now I only try to print the last three messages from the app to the screen. The problem is that emoji are not read correctly. For example, I have a chat where the last three messages are:

14-11-19 09:17 - MyName: This is a test msg

14-11-19 09:17 - MyName: With an emoji

14-11-19 09:17 - MyName:

The  emoji is supposed to be U+0001F602

The  emoji is suppsed to be U+0001F44C U+0001F3FB

My output on android:
[image: o]

If I export the chat as .txt and then use the same program on desktop, my output is correct:
[image].

Here is my code:

**intent_filters.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Main.kv**

```
<AuxScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Nothing here"

<MainScreen>
    loadinglabel : loadinglabel

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id : loadinglabel
            text: "loading..."
            text_size: self.width, None
            halign: 'center'
```

**Main.py**

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

if platform == "android":
    from jnius import autoclass

APP_NAME = "Test"
Builder.load_file("main.kv")
testfile = "mytest.txt" # for debugging on desktop

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.parent_app = App.get_running_app()
        if not (self.parent_app.intent or self.parent_app.chatdata):
            self.add_widget(AuxScreen(name = "aux"))
        else:
            self.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))

class AuxScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    loadinglabel = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda x: self.start_processing(), 1)    

    def start_processing(self):
        if not self.manager.parent_app.chatdata:
            self.manager.parent_app.get_chatdata()
        self.loadinglabel.text = "".join(str(x.encode('unicode-escape')) + "\n" for x in self.manager.parent_app.chatdata[-4:])

class MyApp(App):
    title = APP_NAME

    def __init__(self, intent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.intent = intent
        self.chatdata = None

        # For debugging on linux desktop
        if platform == "linux": 
            filename = testfile # Put here the name of your testfile
            f = open(filename, "r")
            self.chatdata = "".join(l for l in f.readlines()).split('\n')
            f.close() 

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget() 

    def get_chatdata(self):
        InputStreamReader = autoclass('java.io.InputStreamReader')
        BufferedReader = autoclass('java.io.BufferedReader')
        StringBuilder = autoclass('java.lang.StringBuilder')
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')

        activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
        uri = self.intent.getClipData().getItemAt(0).getUri()
        inputstream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
        reader = InputStreamReader(inputstream, "UTF-8")
        recv_stream = BufferedReader(reader)
        data = StringBuilder()
        while True:
            line = recv_stream.readLine()
            if line:
                data.append(line)
                data.append('\n')
            else:
                nextchar = recv_stream.read()
                if nextchar == -1:
                    break
                data.append(chr(nextchar))
        self.chatdata = data.toString().split('\n')
        inputstream.close()

def get_android_intent():
    if platform == "android":
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')

        activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
        intent = activity.getIntent()
        intent_action = intent.getAction()
        if intent and "SEND_MULTIPLE" in intent_action:
            return intent
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    intent = get_android_intent()
    MyApp(intent).run()
```

The buildozer.spec file needs

```
android.manifest.intent_filters = intent_filters.xml
```

The problem is in the get_android_intent or get_chatdata functions. I now next to nothing about Java, so any remarks about these functions are welcome.

If a solution is not possible, I am also happy with an explanation of this behaviour.

Comment: Are you using the same python version on Android?

Comment: yes. I use python3 on both